# How to translate $r=$ equations

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a polar graph function

$$r=2\cdot\sin(\theta)$$

How would I translate (shift) graph $r=2\cdot\sin(\theta)$ with a vector $(^x_y)$?

What I am looking for is a change to the polar function that moves the graph along $x$ by $x$ units and $y$ by $y$ units

---

I realised this is confusing for people. However, I do not understand how. I have always been told that an $r=$ graph is called a polar graph, and that the transformation of shifting is called translating

Comment: Are you sure that should be an $x$ inside the trig functions? Not $\theta$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, I'm just used to pressing $x$ to represent $\theta$

Comment: Also, why is this off-topic?

Comment: Use $x=r\cos\theta,\,\,y=r\sin\theta$. I suppose it could be seen as off topic since you haven't included any attempts you made on this question.

Comment: @JohnDoe , that is an example. This is not for homework. I just want to know because my calculator will not translate graphs for me. I have a CASIO CFX 9850 PLUS

Comment: @JohnDoe Also, that was just an example.

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by "translating graphs". If you wish to plot the graph, you could use an online tool like wolfram alpha. In general, I'd just manipulate the above co-ordinate changes if you want to get rid of polar co-ordinates.

Comment: @JohnDoe the transformation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74639/discussion-between-vortexyt-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom xy=\binom{r\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta}=\binom{f(\theta)\cos\theta}{f(\theta)\sin\theta}$$

Comment: I believe I just multiply it on?

Comment: For $x$, you multiply $r$ by $\cos$ and for $y$, you multiply by $\sin$.

Comment: What am I doing to the function?

Comment: $r=f(\theta)$ is the function. Once you know $f$ and $\theta$ you can work out $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire OP has a graph $r=f(\theta)$, and wants to translate / shift this by a vector $(x,y)$. Unfortunately, the use of $x$ and $y$ as variables led people (myself included) to think that OP wanted to change to cartesian co-ordinates. I don't think this is the case

Answer (score 1):

General equation of a circle in polar coordinates:

$$r^2-2rr_0\cos (\theta-\phi)+r_0^2=R^2$$

Now

$$r=2\sin \theta \implies
r(r-2\sin \theta)=0 \implies
r^2-2r\cos \left( \theta-\frac{\pi}{2} \right)+1=1$$

Hence,
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    r_0\cos \phi &= x \\
    r_0\sin \phi &= y+1
  \end{align}
\right.$$

> The translated circle is
>   $$r^2-2r[x\cos \theta+(y+1)\sin \theta]+x^2+(y+1)^2=1$$

The two roots of $r(\theta)$ represent the same circle but with different senses of rotation.